# WSO2 API Manager Requirements

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've installed WSO2 API Manager and Business Activity Monitor on a Windows 7 test box, and have it configured to use SQL Server as its backend database.  Now I'm trying to determine what we need on our servers for hardware.  On the WSO2 site, it lists the minimum installation hardware requirements:

At least 2 Gb of Ram
At least 180 Mb of disk space, minus log files and databases

What I can't find anywhere is a list of recommended configurations for actual usage.  If I expect to see, say, 10000 API calls in a single day (I don't know this number yet; this is just an example) what should my Windows server configuration look like?  How many servers should I cluster?  How much RAM do I need?  How much disk space should I plan on having for my SQL Server?

Do you know of any sites that detail some of this information, or provide best practices on how to determine it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given number, 10000 API calls per day, it will be enough to have one API Manager server instance in following hardware. You can have another CPU core, and 2 GB RAM for same machine if WSO2 BAM server runs on same machine.

Physical : 3GHz Dual-core Xeon/Opteron (or latest), 4 GB RAM (minimum : 2 GB for JVM and 2GB for the OS, 10GB free disk space (minimum) disk based on the expected storage requirements (calculate by considering the file uploads and the backup policies) .

Virtual Machine : 2 compute units minimum (each unit having 1.0-1.2 GHz Opteron/Xeon processor) 4 GB RAM 10GB free disk space. One cpu unit for OS and one for JVM. (e.g if 3 Carbon instances running require VM of 4 compute units 8 GB RAM 30 GB free space)

NOTE: You may have more than one instance as a cluster for handling high availability concerns etc.

You may also find following articles useful, [1] and [2] are general guides on capacity planing. [3] is a resource used in a meetup and 30/31 slides explains about capacity planing.

Sql server space will depend on your requirements like your data size expected.

[1] http://wso2.com/library/wso2con2013/product-performance-and-topology-sizing

[2] http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2012/11/rightsize-deployment-instances-meet-enterprise-demand/

[3] https://www.dropbox.com/s/66a61d4o5ataxp8/java-colombo-highly-scalable-apps.pptx

Comment: Lahiru, I appreciate this very much!  Where did you find these numbers, though?  Do you have a link to them on the WSO2 site?  I need to have something to show my people.

Comment: We haven't listed those requirement in the site, as the requirements can be depend on use-case(How much API calls per day?). So you can from dev@wso2.org if you need more information.